# IntelliJ: Is it possible to start debugger with breakpoints muted?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Is it possible to start the debugger in IntelliJ IDEA with all breakpoints muted? If so, how?

This would be very useful, as I'm developing a UI application that does a lot of initialization up front. I want to reach the initialized stage, before "un-muting" breakpoints, as there's just too much "noise" during start up, and I need to restart often in this phase of development.

I do not want to disable/enable breakpoints. I know it's possible to temporary mute the breakpoints and how to do it, but I'm asking how to **start the debugger with breakpoints muted** (if that is indeed possible).

I'm currently using IDEA 13, but I can't see any immediate changes since 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please vote for the following intellij idea feature.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82961

Comment: Issue is fixed, will be available in IDEA 14 and now also confirmed for 13.1.x. Go JetBrains! :-)

Comment: For the cases when the old behavior is needed there is a new option switch.
"unmute breakpoints on session finish". Just press Ctrl+Shift+A and type a part of it and switch if off or on.

Answer (score 8):

In the Debug tool window, there's a button called **Mute Breakpoints**. It's on the left-hand side. It looks like a red circle with a slash going through it. [JetBrains help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debug-tool-window.html).

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

You need to start the debugger first, then click that button. That will stop all breakpoints from triggering until you toggle this button back on.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know about this. I'm asking if I can start the debugging session with this option already enabled, to avoid clicking every time I start.

Comment: I think Sean Landsman's answer is the alternative. In the Breakpoints window, all the breakpoints are rolled up into categories (line, exception, etc.). You can bulk enable/disable breakpoints by clicking the checkbox next to the category. What would be the difference between muting breakpoints by default and disabling all breakpoints before you start the debugger?

Comment: Fair enough. I really appreciate you guys' effort. It's just not what I was asking. I just want the button you have marked in your screenshot above *selected when I start debugging*. (Ie: Clicking mute is 1 click. Disabling the breakpoints does something different. Let's say I have 12 breakpoints in the code, and 5 of them disabled. If I disable them all, I then need to re-enable (and remember) the 7 breakpoints that I wanted. And do this for every restart-cycle. This equals multiple clicks. => No gain. I was hoping for 0 clicks :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

You could try unchecking them all before starting the session:

Try: CTRL+SHIFT+F8 and deselecting the breakpoints you want to ignore

Once debugging you can open the breakpoint dialog again and select the ones you want to activate

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately this is slower than what I do now, which is muting all breakpoints as soon as I start a session. I'm trying to optimize the workflow, as I restart the application quite often...